# Why am I unable to delete records on local service based database with EF 6?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following code to delete all records from a table. The table is in a local Service-based Database that will hold temporary pricing data on a desktop app. When this code runs, it logs that it connects, deletes, and commits the transaction. I can see that it has 1500 delete logs which matches the row count. But when I go to the table in Visual Studio, all the data is still there like nothing was deleted. If I run this code on my instance of full SQL server, I can delete rows just as expected. Does EF not work with local service based DB's? My work around is to use SQLCommand/SQLConnection etc, which works just fine. What am I missing here?

```
using (var context = new PriceListLocalEntities())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;            
    context.PRICE_LIST.RemoveRange(context.PRICE_LIST.Where(x => x.PRICE_ID != null));
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: check the connectionstring and is it the same as when you edit by hand? and, is mdf file in your project(if is, then check the file's build action)?

Comment: The connection string in my Entity model does not contain my project directory filepath. It has |DataDirectory| instead. There are two .mdf files, one in the project folder and one in the bin folder. My SqlConnection code that does delete the data uses the full filepath to the project folder. The build action for the database is set to "content".

Comment: that is the root cause, visual studio copies and overwrites the file in bin folder after every compile, you can try some change to other build action(and most importantly there's another property, copy to bin folder, to never)

Comment: You put me on the right track. I did some more reading and found the issue. My entity model is pointing at the output DB, while my raw ADO.net is pointing at the projectDB. I'm unable to point EF towards to project db as it says it cannot connect, and the raw ado.net cannot connect to the output database. EF is literally minutes slower for bulk operations, which is why I use both types of data access.

Comment: the best way is to create database separately, i never use local db since it is confusing, i think the only advantage is it can be easily created within visual studio.

Comment: When you say separately, do you mean in an instance of SQL server? This is just a single temp table, which is why I opted to wrap it up in the app.

Comment: you can't wrap anything without installing sqlserver. you can try deploying your current working binaries to a pc without sqlserver and you'll fail.

Comment: Got it. Which database platform would you suggest for a small local temp table? I suppose I could keep it in working memory as a datatable.

Comment: sqlite is widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a service based DB in Visual Studio, a copy of the .mdf file is copied to the output folder. An Entity Model connects to the output version, while raw ADO.NET connects to the project version. Using both types of ADO.NET in the same app with access and update them separately. Which doesn't work for operations that are dependent on each other.